# SQLAlchemy - how to get raw SQL of `.count()` queries?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The simplest possible way to get "raw" SQL for any query is just `print` it (actually, convert it to `str`).

*But*, this is not working for `count()` queries because `count()` is "firing" method - a method which is stated as "This results in an execution of the underlying query". Other "firing" methods include `all()`, `first()` and so on.

How to get SQL for such methods?

I'm especially interested in `count()` because it transforms underlying query in some way (actually, this way is described explicitly [in docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count), but things may vary). Other methods can alter resulting SQL as well, for example, `first()`.

So, sometimes it is useful to get raw SQL of such queries in order to investigate how thing goes under the hood.

I read answers about "getting raw SQL" but this case is special because such methods *don't return `Query` objects*.

Note that I mean that I need a SQL of *existing* `Query` objects which are already constructed in some way.

Comment: Maybe using `func.count()` might work instead of `query.count()`?

Comment: Did you mean `func.count(query)`? If so, then no, it doesn't work. It even produces malformed SQL which can't be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example will return a count of any query object, which you should then be able to convert to a string representation:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

...

existing_query = session.query(Something)\
    .join(OtherThing)\
    .filter(OtherThing.foo = 'FOO')\
    .subquery()

query = session.query(func.count(existing_query.c.bar).label('bar_count'))

print(query)

actual_count = query.as_scalar()  # Executes query
```

Notice that you have to specify a field from the query output to count. In the example defined by `existing_query.c.bar`.

Comment: I've already some query object - it has filters, joins, etc. I want to get SQL of it. Such `Query` object is not equivalent to `sess.query(func.count(Model.id).label('some_count'))`.

Comment: @tosh you can at any time change your existing query to a subquery by calling `query.subquery()`. Then it is just a matter of counting one of the fields in it. See edit. That said. Next time you should follow [Stack Overflows MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): It is hard to guess every contingency in your particular case without knowing exactly what you are trying to do.